# How to ignore same values on ChartJs?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have weird problem to solve.When repeated values exist on data array of chartjs,I want to ignore them(not removing).Because if I remove them or set null,then they will be seem not exaclty I want.Here below what I want to achieve

[image]

```
data: [500, 500,    2424,   2424,   4111, 4111, 80, 5555,   5555, 6811]
```

When next value is duplicated,then somehow it should be between next and previous value.I couldnt figure that out and didn't know where to start.

Here codepen: https://codepen.io/Cicek96/pen/OJyevXb

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');


var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["Tokyo", "Mumbai", "Mexico City", "Shanghai", "Sao Paulo", "New York", "Karachi","Buenos Aires", "Delhi","Moscow"],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Series 1', // Name the series
            data: [500, 500, 2424, 2424, 4111, 4111, 80, 5555, 5555, 6811], // Specify the data values array
            fill: false,
            borderColor: '#2196f3', // Add custom color border (Line)
            backgroundColor: '#2196f3', // Add custom color background (Points and Fill)
            borderWidth: 1 // Specify bar border width
        }]},
    options: {
      responsive: true, // Instruct chart js to respond nicely.
      maintainAspectRatio: false, // Add to prevent default behaviour of full-width/height 
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

null dupes and use spanGaps: true to make it draw over dupes

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');

const nullDupes = data => data.map((x, i) => data[i - 1] === x ? null : x);

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Tokyo", "Mumbai", "Mexico City", "Shanghai", "Sao Paulo", "New York", "Karachi", "Buenos Aires", "Delhi", "Moscow"],
    datasets: [{
      spanGaps: true,
      label: 'Series 1', // Name the series
      data: nullDupes([500, 500, 2424, 2424, 4111, 4111, 80, 5555, 5555, 6811]), // Specify the data values array
      fill: false,
      borderColor: '#2196f3', // Add custom color border (Line)
      backgroundColor: '#2196f3', // Add custom color background (Points and Fill)
      borderWidth: 1 // Specify bar border width
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true, // Instruct chart js to respond nicely.
    maintainAspectRatio: false, // Add to prevent default behaviour of full-width/height 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Great solution.Is there anyway to make it in one map only instead of two maps?